# Can't get call and message notification on my Mac

Tags: macbook-pro, messages, facetime

I have just purchased a new MacBook Pro 2019 with Ventura 13.4. On my iPhone I am logging in with the same Apple ID. However, When I am getting a call on my iPhone, I don't get any notification on my Mac.

I see my iPhone in Connected Devices on my Mac. On call setting I see my MacBook in "Calls on other devices"

Not sure what else to check.

**Update:**

I enabled the wifi calling on my phone as well. And both my phone and mac is connected to the same wifi. I'm still not getting any call.

And when I try to call from my mac. I am getting following error message

[image]

**Update 2**
my Iphone and Macbook are connected to same Wifi (my home wifi). However, when I am connected to company VPN from my macbook, I don't get any phone notification or can't make any calls from my macbook. I can still get message notification and send messages.

However, if I disconnect from company VPN I can make calls and receive notification as well.

so why, I can get/receive message while I am on VPN but not calls ?

Comment: Are you receiving calls (mobile or FaceTime) and iMessages on your MacBook?  With a friend close by, have them call your cell and see if the call rings through on your Mac.  Same for iMessage.

Comment: I am able to see messages and call from someone in my contact list but not from like those numbers which sends OTP.  for them it shows me phone number in imessage but message it self is always empty.

Comment: That’s not what I asked, plus what you’re describing is a whole new issue.

Comment: I am getting the notification for the message but not for the call. I tried calling from my mac as well and it's not going anywhere

Comment: Do you have WiFi calling enabled?

Comment: nope. do I need to ?

Comment: To receive calls on your Mac, yes.  You don’t get notifications on a device that doesn’t receive the event.

Comment: VPN? Corporate WiFi?  This is called “issue creep”.  Can you describe exactly what you’re dealing with so we can get a clear picture is the problem?

Comment: sorry for confusion, I edited the question. should be more clear now.